# Use 'this' in Firebase promise with React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, es6-promise

I am having trouble using `this` inside a Firebase.promise `.then(` callback.
Here's what I have:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username,
         this.state.password).then(function (result) {
           console.log("AUTH OK " + result.provider + " " + result.uid);
           this.props.navigator.push('main_page'); // Can't do this.. or anything using ''this'

        }, (error) => {  // es6 syntax fat arrow syntax to ensure 'this' is in scope
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        this.setState({errorMessage: errorMessage});

      }
    );
```

I know about the ES 6 fat arrow syntax, but can't use the same for the then, for some reason.

It would seem like something that someone else has solved, but can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also solve this with `bind`, like so:

```
  .then(function() { ... }.bind(this),
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascripts `this` only refers to the current scope of the function. If you change your code like so:

```
var scope = this;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(scope.state.username, scope.state.password).then(function (result) {
    console.log("AUTH OK " + result.provider + " " + result.uid);
    scope.props.navigator.push('main_page'); // Can't do this.. or anything using ''this'
}, (error) => { // es6 syntax fat arrow syntax to ensure 'this' is in scope
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    scope.setState({
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    });

});
```

It should eliminate the problem.